# UISearchBar in navigationbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

How can I show a UISearchBar in the NavigationBar?

I can't figure out how to do this.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To put searchBar into the center of navigationBar:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBarTop;
```

To put searchBar to the left/right side of navigationBar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarItem;
```

Comment: I have the problem that on iPad the results are shown in a table view embedded in a popover, instead of in the frame of the original table view. Any solution to this?

Comment: If I set it like this, the `searchDisplayController` doesn't show up anymore. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method isn't called either.
With `searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` works but I can't use it because I'm supporting iOS 6 too...

Comment: This approach hides the title

Comment: self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar     if you you want it in centre this works

Answer (score 20):

As of iOS 7, the UISearchDisplayController supports this by default. Set the UISearchDisplayController's `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES` to get this working easily.

Per the documentation:

> Starting in iOS 7.0, you can use a search display controller with a navigation bar (an instance of the UINavigationBar class) by configuring the search display controller’s displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar and navigationItem properties.

Comment: According the Apple's docs, it looks like we can't set the searchBar in the titleView. Am I right? Can you show us how you set the navigationItem of the searchDisplayController? Thank you

Comment: I tried this but my search bar is in the middle of the screen!

Comment: The easiest way when using Storyboards is to drag a Search Bar and Search Display Controller out of the Utility Area into the bottom of the current scene inside Document Outline. After that just add `self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;` in viewdidload. You may want to show a cancel button or hide the backbutton while editing so this could be done in the delegate implementation.

Comment: This makes the search bar occupy the whole navigation bar, hiding any existing leftbar and rightbarbuttons. How can I still keep those?

Comment: @fishinear, check out the answer i just posted on how to add a searchdisplaycontroller to your navigation while maintaining the left/right bar button items.

Comment: @VanDuTran I had this issue when I assigned searchbar to tableview header, when I removed I've got another problem — search results table view shows only on first search.

Answer (score 12):

As one commenter noted, using `searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true` ends up hiding any existing left/right bar button items.

I've found two different ways of adding a `searchBar` to a `navigationBar` using iOS7's new property on `searchDisplayController`.

**1) Nib Based Approach**

If you're using a .xib, you can set a User Defined Runtime Attribute for this value and for whatever reason, the leftBarButtonItem stays in tact. I have not tested it with a rightBarButtonItem.

[image]

**2) Code (Timing Matters)**

If you want to implement in code, timing seems to matter. It seems that you must add the `searchBar` to the `navigationBar` first, then set your `barButtonItem`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem new];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried (1) in storyboard and it crashes. this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar.'

Comment: You can do it in a StoryBoard, but you need to set it on the Search Display Controller, not on the View Controller; however, it doesn't preserve the right button item in my test, but it does put the search bar in the navbar.

Comment: You can use #2 with UIBarButtonItems setup in a StoryBoard that have a referencing outlet.  Instead of [UIBarButtonItem new] above do: ```self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.leftButton``` (where self.leftButton is the outlet for the left button).

Comment: It appears that SearchDisplayController had been deprecated since iOS 8.0.

Comment: Ray Weinerlich has a good tutorial on this http://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

Answer (score 11):

Check out Apple's [UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code. It shows how to use the new `UISearchController` in three different ways: modally, in nav bar, and below the navigation bar.

Comment: These samples helped me incredibly much. Thank you!

Comment: I took a break from iOS for a few years and missed lots of UIKit updates. This is so helpful.  Apple really needs better organization of their docs.  I have spent countless hours going through the WWDC vids/samples, searching the Documentation Archive, and I have never seen this.  Thanks for sharing

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but it seems that the latest version only contains two examples, Default and Custom, neither of which has it in the nav bar :(

Answer (score 2):

**Objective C code snippet for UISearchBar in NavigationBar**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UISearchController *searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController;
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar;
    }
}
```

Read more [here](https://blog.kiprosh.com/ios-11-new-navigation-bar-and-search-controller/)

Comment: It still working on iOS 12. Clean solution for Objective-C devs :)