# Search bar transition

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I want to animate a search bar transition to the navigation bar whenever the user clicks the "search" button on the left of the navigation bar or when the user clicks the search bar itself. I want the same transition that is done by the "contacts" app.

My app layout:

[image: app layout]

I googled a lot but could not find any code that helps me to accomplish this.

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Look into `UISearchController` (or the recently deprecated `UISearchDisplayController`).

Comment: Take a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095477/uisearchbar-in-navigationbar