# Swift : searchbar - make some search suggestions

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I am new to ios developpement and I am just trying to figure out the best way to do the following tasks:

It is the first time that I will try to use search bar, I would like to implemented like apple mail native apps, what I like about apple native app search is when u click inside the textfield of the search bar , all the emails will disappear and instead there is a suggestion research "search suggestion" are proposed like following picture: ( sorry i am a french guy)

[image]

Well I don’t know if it is a new tableview over the email tableview or it is the same email tableview and the customisation was hard coded.

Thank you all for advices

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095477/uisearchbar-in-navigationbar

Comment: the link above not answering my question about search suggestion

Comment: Depends on you requirements and data you want to sort. But in general cells for suggestions is different to cells from content, so perhaps it should be different controller. In mail it's definitely different controller.

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov so that mean i have to handle two UItableviews (Show/hide when search is cliked) ?