# How to animate in a search bar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uiviewanimation

I need some help with animiting (sliding in) a search bar using swift, I've tried looking up tutorials etc but I can't seem to find anything.
A visual representation would be something like this:

[image]

When I click the magnifying glass icon on the right of the navigation bar, I want the search bar to slide in from the left. All the tutorials that I found were about creating search bars under navigation bars or static ones etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out `navigationItem.titleView` to place the search bar directly on the navigation bar, but implementing the animation you desire will be a very tricky. Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095477/uisearchbar-in-navigationbar) question which contains some tips regarding your question.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look!

Answer (score 0):

First i declare the search bar:

```
var searchBar: UISearchBar!
```

on viewDidLoad() function i initiated the searchbar as follows:

```
self.searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x:300, y:0, width:300, height:20))
```

When the magnifying glass is clicked, i run the following code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
    self.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:300, height:20)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement UISearchBarDelegate and play with some kind of alpha or size animations like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: { /*animate here*/ }, completion:  nil)
    }
}
```