# UISearchBar is flickering in UINavigationBar with Large Titles

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a `UINavigationController`-based app and want to do it in iOS 12 style: with large titles and the `SearchBar` displayed inside the `NavigationBar`.

Unfortunately, I have this problem that the `SearchBar` will briefly disappear as soon as the animation to the next (or previous) View Controller starts. Once the animation is finished, the Search Bar is visible again. One has to look closely to see it, but if you use the swipe gesture to go back you can see the effect very good.

[UISearchBar disappeares when animation between View Controller starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFxj8.gif)

In order to reproduce the issue outside of my full app I created a simple little app with a `UINavigationController` as initial `ViewController` and a plain `ViewController` (with just a "**Next**" Button) as `RootViewController` in there. Large Titles are set to Automatic in the `NavigationItem`, and on the `NavigationBar` "Prefers Large Titles" is set to True. In `viewDidLoad` in the view controller I assign an instance of `UISearchController` to the `NavigationItem` as simple as this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
}
```

The "Next" button has a "**Show**" `Segue` to its surrounding View Controller, so I will be able to push the same View Controller over and over again for testing.

What I want is the same behavior as in the iOS 12 Files App: There, the `SearchBar` remains static within the `NavigationBar` even when navigation happens.

I already spent some good time searching for a solution but could not really find something.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095477/uisearchbar-in-navigationbar

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot see anything in there that might help with my Search Bar briefly disappearing when going back and forward in the navigation stack. The problem is not that the Search Bar is not visible at all or something like this. Basically functionality-wise everything is working fine, I just think it should not flicker as it does not do that in iOS 12's Files app.

Comment: @vikash-kumar Thanks for showing me how to improve the formatting. I'm new here so I'm always learning...